# Lock legacy blackberry device

Tags: blackberry

I have a situation in which i want to lock our blackberry device remotely. Is it possible to invoke our blackberry agent remotely which resides in blackberry device. Or is there any other possibility to do that?

Also, let me know if this is possible only using **BIS** or if we can do it using a normal WiFi connection.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're looking for?  Are you looking to write an *agent* application that gets installed on the devices, and then be able to communicate with that agent via some kind of remote push notification to lock the device?   Are you trying to lock out users, for example, if the device is stolen?

Comment: Thanks for reply... yes i am looking for same as you understand

Comment: Have you had a look at BlackBerry Protect?  I've not looked at it seriously, but I think it can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I got the answer.. It it black berry push service which can be use to invoke our device agent through the push notification.